# PHP/regex to parse NGINX error log

Tags: php, regex

The error entry looks like:

```
2011/06/10 13:30:10 [error] 23263#0: *1 directory index of "/var/www/ssl/" is forbidden, client: 86.186.86.232, server: hotelpublisher.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "hotelpublisher.com"
```

I need to parse:

```
date/time
error type
error message
client
server
request
host
```

The first bit (parsing date) is easy using `substr`. Though my `REGEX` is not too good and I am hoping to hear a better solution. Simply exploding by `,` won't work as well, I guess, since error can potentially contain a comma as well.

What is the most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I did it.

```
$error      = array();

$error['date']          = strtotime(substr($line, 0, 19));

$line                   = substr($line, 20);
$error_str              = explode(': ', strstr($line, ', client:', TRUE), 2);

$error['message']       = $error_str[1];

preg_match("|\[([a-z]+)\] (\d+)#(\d+)|", $error_str[0], $matches);

$error['error_type']    = $matches[1];


$args_str   = explode(', ', substr(strstr($line, ', client:'), 2));
$args       = array();

foreach($args_str as $a)
{
    $name_value = explode(': ', $a, 2);

    $args[$name_value[0]]   = trim($name_value[1], '"');
}

$error  = array_merge($error, $args);

die(var_dump( $error ));
```

Which will produce:

```
array(7) {
  ["date"]=>
  int(1307709010)
  ["message"]=>
  string(50) "*1 directory index of "/var/www/ssl/" is forbidden"
  ["error_type"]=>
  string(5) "error"
  ["client"]=>
  string(13) "86.186.86.232"
  ["server"]=>
  string(18) "hotelpublisher.com"
  ["request"]=>
  string(14) "GET / HTTP/1.1"
  ["host"]=>
  string(18) "hotelpublisher.com"
}
```

Just want to see few votes to know which is the preferred option regarding performance/reliability.

Answer (score 4):

What about:

```
$str = '2011/06/10 13:30:10 [error] 23263#0: *1 directory index of "/var/www/ssl/" is forbidden, client: 86.186.86.232, server: hotelpublisher.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "hotelpublisher.com"';
preg_match('~^(?P<datetime>[\d+/ :]+) \[(?P<errortype>.+)\] .*?: (?P<errormessage>.+), client: (?P<client>.+), server: (?P<server>.+), request: (?P<request>.+), host: (?P<host>.+)$~', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

**output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2011/06/10 13:30:10 [error] 23263#0: *1 directory index of "/var/www/ssl/" is forbidden, client: 86.186.86.232, server: hotelpublisher.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "hotelpublisher.com"
    [datetime] => 2011/06/10 13:30:10
    [1] => 2011/06/10 13:30:10
    [errortype] => error
    [2] => error
    [errormessage] => *1 directory index of "/var/www/ssl/" is forbidden
    [3] => *1 directory index of "/var/www/ssl/" is forbidden
    [client] => 86.186.86.232
    [4] => 86.186.86.232
    [server] => hotelpublisher.com
    [5] => hotelpublisher.com
    [request] => "GET / HTTP/1.1"
    [6] => "GET / HTTP/1.1"
    [host] => "hotelpublisher.com"
    [7] => "hotelpublisher.com"
)
```

Comment: There is a small mistake, see `errortype`, though I guess that would work as well.

Comment: @Guy: what error type is suppose to be? Just number before `#` ?

Comment: It can be error/notice/warn, etc. It is the text in brackets `[]`.

Comment: I added some small improves in the regexp: const nginxError = "^(?P<time>[\\d+/ :]+) \\[(?P<severity>.+)\\] .*?: (?P<message>.+), client: (?P<client>.+), server: (?P<server>.+), request: \"(?P<method>\\S+) (?P<path>\\S+) (?P<version>.+?)\", host: \"(?P<host>.+)\"$"

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
$str = '2011/06/10 13:30:10 [error] 23263#0: *1 directory index of "/var/www/ssl/" is forbidden, client: 86.186.86.232, server: hotelpublisher.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "hotelpublisher.com"';
preg_match('~^(\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\s\[([^]]*)\]\s[^:]*:\s(.*?)\sclient:\s([^,]*),\sserver:\s([^,]*),\srequest:\s"([^"]*)",\shost:\s"([^"]*)"~', $str, $m );
list($line, $dateTime, $type, $msg, $client, $server, $request, $host ) = $m;

var_dump($dateTime);
var_dump($type);
var_dump($msg);
var_dump($client);
var_dump($server);
var_dump($request);
var_dump($host);
```

#### OUTPUT

```
string(19) "2011/06/10 13:30:10"
string(5) "error"
string(60) "*1 directory index of "/var/www/ssl/" is forbidden,"
string(13) "86.186.86.232"
string(18) "hotelpublisher.com"
string(14) "GET / HTTP/1.1"
string(18) "hotelpublisher.com"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have access to formatting the log file, this will do:

```
$regex = '~(\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2}) (\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}) \[(\w+)\] (.*?) client: (\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}), server: (.*?), request: "(.*?)", host: "(.*?)"~';
preg_match($regex, $line, $matches);
list($all,$date,$time,$type,$message,$client,$server,$request,$host) = $matches;
```

If you *do* have access to how the log is formatted, put the message at the end instead of the middle, then you can do:

```
$log_arr = explode(', ', $line, 7);
list($date,$time,$type,$client,$server,$request,$host,$message) = $matches;
```

The secret is that `explode` takes an optional third argument, limiting the number of elements to split apart. So by setting it to `8`, the remainder of the line will be stored as the last element in the returned array. [See the manual](https://www.php.net/explode) for more information on this.

Answer (score 0):

Please check [Nginx Error Log Reader](http://gadelkareem.com/2012/07/01/nginx-error-log-reader/); a php reader/parser for Nginx error log file. the script is able to read error logs recursively and display them in a user friendly table. Script configuration includes the number of bytes to read per page and allow pagination through the error log.