# How read nginx-logs in symfony-admin?

Tags: symfony, logging

I want to read nginx access-log files in admin and filter data by some parameters (url, date and etc). Maybe exist some bundles for do this?

Comment: Just parse it with a regex http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6307203/php-regex-to-parse-nginx-error-log

Comment: @absalon.valdes It's very simple, but I need write filters, unzip old files and some other things. I hope some bundles for this is exist.